# Does Robocopy's /ZB option switch modes on a per file or per transfer basis?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, robocopy

Robocopy's command guide describes `/zb` as an option that *"Copies files in restartable mode. If file access is denied, switches to backup mode."*
However, this is somewhat ambiguous. When transferring multiple files, if access is denied to one, will Robocopy switch to backup mode for that one file, and then switch back to restartable mode for further files, or will it remain in backup mode until the transfer ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not recommended, because it does exactly what it says:

If file access is denied, Robocopy will start itself in backup mode,
meaning not in restartable mode. All following file copies will start
from the first byte without checking if the file was already partially
transferred.